# How do I preform the inverse key expansion of aes decryption?

Tags: aes, block-cipher, decryption, key-schedule

I’m working on an aes encryption and decryption project in 8086 assembly!
I managed to code an encryption algorithm and it worked perfectly.

No I’m working on the decryption algorithm.
I’ve managed to code all the inverse transformations.
But how about the inverse key expansion??

How is the aes key expansion preformed during the decryption process??
Thanks,
Ilay